# in-App purchase backend service

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there an online solution like UrbanAirship that provide a backend system to manage IAP within an app? UrbanAirship revised their product scheme, and currently IAP functionality can be found either in the Basic (which costs 10 cents per user, along with 10 centres per registration) or the Enterprise subscription which is targeting publishers with more than 100,000 active users. any alternatives? Thanks

Cheers

Comment: Try out Applicasa<br> www.applicasa.com <br>
backend solution for apps
Database, cms, API's, push messages, Ad Hoc, all the good stuff you might need